# Google Cast receiver returns 404 not found for all MP4 video URLs

Tags: android, video-streaming, chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to load MP4 videos on my registered StyledMediaReceiver through my Android sender app with this code:

```
mediaMetadata = new MediaMetadata(
            MediaMetadata.MEDIA_TYPE_MOVIE);
    mediaMetadata.putString(MediaMetadata.KEY_TITLE, "My video");
    mediaInfo = new MediaInfo.Builder(
            "https://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-
             bucket/sample/DesigningForGoogleCast.mp4")
            .setContentType("video/mp4")
            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_BUFFERED)
            .setMetadata(mediaMetadata).build();
    try {
        mRemoteMediaPlayer
                .load(mGoogleApiClient, mediaInfo, true)
    }
```

However, the receiver always logs a 404 Not Found error for any link to an MP4 video. This is the log that I get:

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
cast_receiver.js:37  [  0.266s] [cast.receiver.CastReceiverManager] Version: 2.0.0.0029
cast_receiver.js:37  [  0.317s] [goog.net.WebSocket] Opening the WebSocket on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc
cast_receiver.js:26 Mixed Content: The page at 'https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/player.html?skin' was loaded over HTTPS, but attempted to connect to the insecure WebSocket endpoint 'ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc'. This endpoint should be available via WSS. Insecure access is deprecated.
cast_receiver.js:26 Connecting to a non-secure WebSocket server from a secure origin is deprecated.
cast_receiver.js:37  [  0.385s] [goog.net.WebSocket] WebSocket opened on ws://localhost:8008/v2/ipc
https://www.gstatic.com/eureka/player/undefined Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

Can someone please point me towards a solution to this problem?

Comment: I don't see anything here in the log showing it got a 404 when trying to load the video; that video is accessible to public and the server won't give you a 404. You might want to capture more of the log to see what is going on.

In addition, try CastVideos-android app which uses the very same videos and see if you run into any issues with that.

Comment: Thanks, Ali! The CastVideos-android app was able to cast this video normally. After seeing this, I rewrote my app using the Cast Companion Library that the above demo app uses to load the video like this:`mCastManager.loadMedia(mediaInfo,true,0);`. Now the video plays but keeps buffering constantly. The demo app, however, plays this video smoothly. What would cause this observed difference?.

Comment: Look at the receiver's log file to see what is happening....